# [Fedora 14][LVM2&EXT4] Overwritten partition config

Tags: fedora, lvm, data-recovery, ext4, overwrite

- Accidentally, I deleted my '/etc' & '/bin' folder (I know, my fault).
- Then, I boot liveCD and tried to copy or fix this issue.
- And then when I can't figure nothing to fix it, I don't know why, I  want install system on my existing system, and I thought that new installation don't touch and change my /home folder. This step Was my biggest mistake, after this I get raw /home partition without my data.

Now, I'm trying recovery my data from `/home`, and i don't know how do this. I'm using program testdisk but I don't know how it work with `lvm` and `ext4`.

Can I recover content of `/home` or it's impossible?

If you need more logs please tell my what command to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try extundelete. It's in yum and may be available in LiveCD distributions.

Comment: I tried it, but this program recover some junk and nothing valuables. 
Anyway, Thanks for advice.